# How do I disable RTCPeerConnection?

Tags: ip-address, webrtc, tor

I went to check if my IP was leaking so I went to [Ipleak](http://ipleak.net), and sure enough, there was my IP found through WebRTC detection.

I then used [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) and went to the same website and instead of showing some IP it said that "No leak, RTCPeerConnection not available." So now I ask, is there any way to disable RTCPeerConnection and is there a reason I shouldn't?

EDIT: It should also be noted that I was using the extension Zenmate for Chrome.

Comment: Note that [ipleak](http://ipleak.net/) first shows you your *public* IP address. This is visible as part of normal web traffic, and is how servers talk to you, so disabling `RTCPeerConnection` is not sufficient to hide that. Further down it also shows you your LAN IP address, the non-unique IP of your machine on your local network, which `RTCPeerConnection` does expose. Tor hides both using an elaborate cluster of proxy servers (and it also disables WebRTC).

Comment: Well that was the question, how do I disable WebRTC and is there any reason I shouldn't? WebRTC exposes my IP even when using a proxy. If I turn on a VPN it does not expose my IP but my VPN is a lot worse than the proxy I have. The only way I've found is using an extension that disables all scripts on a website but that is not very reliable as don't want to disable all scripts :(

Comment: The [instructions at ipleak](https://ipleak.net/#webrtcleak) are correct AFAIK. Only Firefox lets you turn off WebRTC entirely at the moment, whereas the Chrome instructions didn't work for me with ZenMate, though that may be a VPN configuration issue (probably only does HTTP* vs. all default route traffic?) - I believe both browsers are working on other options here.

Comment: Thank you for this, I guess I'll have to use Firefox to feel 100% secure (or tor).

Answer (score 0):

I read your question a few days ago and now I come across a FAQ in which it is explained for the different browsers (also chrome on different OSs):

https://www.ivpn.net/knowledgebase/158/My-IP-is-being-leaked-by-WebRTC-How-do-I-disable-it.html